# Project can not find template with key _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, razor, .net-5, razorlight

I'm struggling to make email work while working with embedded resource for `_Layout.cshtml` in `FluentEmail`.

This is the exception error I'm getting:

```
Project can not find template with key _Layout.cshtml
```

This is my setup so far:

Inside the ConfigureServices in `Program.cs`, I've added the `RazorRenderer` as:

```
//Set email service using FluentEmail
 services.AddFluentEmail("appname@domain.com")
 .AddRazorRenderer(typeof(Program))
 .AddSmtpSender("smtp.somesmtp.com", 25)
 .AddSmtpSender(new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient() { });
```

Inside my `NotificationService.cs`, I always fall into that exception block:

```
private async Task SendEmailAsync<TModel>(string subject, TModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var email = await scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFluentEmail>()
                    .To(string.Join(";", _emailRecipients))
                    .Subject(subject)
                    .UsingTemplateFromEmbedded("AppName.Views.Emails.SomeReport.cshtml", model, GetType().Assembly)
                    .SendAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to send email. Check exception for more information.");
    }
}
```

`SomeReport.cshtml` is inside `Views\Emails\SomeReport.cshtml` which looks like this:

```
@using System;
@using RazorLight;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using AppName.Models;

@inherits TemplatePage<IEnumerable<SomeReport>>
@{
    @* For working with Embedded Resource Views *@
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}

@* Work with the Model here... *@
```

`_Layout.cshtml` is inside `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` which looks like this:

```
@using RazorLight;
@* Some common layout styles here *@
@RenderBody()
```

Both the `SomeReport.cshtml` and `_Layout.cshtml` are Embedded resources:

[image]

My references has `RazorLight` through `FluentEmail.Razor` package.

[image]

If it helps, this is a `.NET 5 Worker Service` project and I've also added `PreserveCompilationContext` and `PreserveCompilationReferences` in the `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  <PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've looked at everywhere and still haven't found a solution to this. Something this simple has been such a struggle to make work. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: any update on this? Did you got this working? or gave up?

Comment: @JawandSingh I made it to work today . Check out my accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

**Point to Note 1:**

Specifying the path to `_Layout.cshtml` in your Views must be relative to the embedded resource root you enter while adding FluentEmail.
For eg:

```
.AddRazorRenderer(typeof(Program))
```

Since my `Program.cs` and `Views` folder are in the same level, to locate `_Layout.cshtml` by `SomeReport.cshtml`, my path needs to be:

```
@{
    Layout = "Views.Shared._Layout.cshtml";
}
```

**Point to Note 2:**

Specifying the path to your View needs to be the ***full path*** starting from your Assembly name.
For eg:

```
var razorTemplatePath = "AppName.Views.Emails.SomeReport.cshtml";
```

It works like a charm now!

---

### My full setup

Inside the `ConfigureServices` method in `Program.cs` -->

```
// Set email service using FluentEmail
services.AddFluentEmail("appname@domain.com")
        // For Fluent Email to find _Layout.cshtml, just mention here where your views are. This took me hours to figure out. - AshishK
        //.AddRazorRenderer(@$"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/Views/")
        .AddRazorRenderer(typeof(Program)) //If you want to use views as embedded resource, use this
        .AddSmtpSender("smtp.somesmtp.com", 25)
        .AddSmtpSender(new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient() { });
```

Inside my `FluentEmailService.cs`:

```
public class FluentEmailService
{
    private readonly IFluentEmailFactory _fluentEmailFactory;
    private readonly ILogger<FluentEmailService> _logger;

    // Keep in mind that only the Singleton services can be injected through the constructor - AshishK.
    public FluentEmailService(ILogger<FluentEmailService> logger, IFluentEmailFactory fluentEmailFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _fluentEmailFactory = fluentEmailFactory;
    }

    public async Task<SendResponse> SendEmailAsync<TModel>(string subject, string razorTemplatePath, TModel model, string semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipients)
    {
        try
        {
            // var razorTemplatePathExample = "AppName.Views.Emails.SomeReport.cshtml";
            // var semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipientsExample = "CoolGuy@company.com;ChillGuy@company.com";
            // 'model' is whatever you send to the View. For eg: @model IEnumerable<SomeReport> that we put at the top of SomeReport.cshtml view (see below).

            var email = await _fluentEmailFactory
                            .Create()
                            .To(semicolonSeparatedEmailRecipients)
                            .Subject(subject)
                            .UsingTemplateFromEmbedded(razorTemplatePath, model, GetType().Assembly) //If you want to use embedded resource Views.
                            .SendAsync();
            return email;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to send email. Check exception for more information.");
            return new SendResponse() { ErrorMessages = new string[] { ex.Message } };
        }
    }
}
```

The properties of my Views (`SomeReport.cshtml`, `_Layout.cshtml`) look like this:

[image]

(You don't need to do this for `_ViewImports.cshtml` and `_ViewStart.cshtml`.)

My View `SomeReport.cshtml` is inside `Views\Emails\SomeReport.cshtml` and looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeReport>

@{
    Layout = "Views.Shared._Layout.cshtml";
}

@* Work with the Model here... *@
```

`_Layout.cshtml` is inside `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

My references has `RazorLight` through `FluentEmail.Razor` package.

[image]

The settings for Razorlight looks like this in my .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- This group contains project properties for RazorLight on .NET Core -->
  <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
  <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

Comment: Hey thanks, I also got it working somehow after experimenting on a sample project. My case was `Views` are in Web Project and `Mailer` code is in Domain Project and Web consumes Domain Project as reference.

Comment: Thank you for saving my hairs being torn out :D This isn't even written down in the documentation, these descrptions should be copied to docs as well. Clearly explained, in and out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Tell Razorlight that you are using embedded resources like this:

```
Email.DefaultRenderer = new RazorRenderer(typeof(Assembly.SomeClassInsideAssembly));
```

OR in Startup:

```
.AddRazorRenderer(typeof(Assembly.SomeClassInsideAssembly));
```

Then inside your view specify your layout page relative to "SomeClassInsideAssembly":

```
@{
    Layout = "Views._Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template instead of:

```
Layout = "_Layout.cshtml"
```

try:

```
Layout = ""./Shared/_Layout.cshtml""
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't fix anything.